# How does q.alt param work when q is specified

Tags: solr, lucene

I referred [this section](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/the-dismax-query-parser.html#q-alt-parameter)

I made `q` as empty and added a query `q.alt=NAME:tokyo` with `dismax` parser. It worked as expected.

I added a query in `q` as `NAME:london` It returned nothing. I expected to return the docs which matches `NAME:london`

To find out the reason I enabled `debugQuery` and the query is translated as `+DisjunctionMaxQuery:(((NAME:name:london) ^ 1.0) ())`

I couldn't understand this translation. Could anyone clarify this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dismax parser does not support the Lucene syntax (`field:value`). The `edismax` (the e signifies the Extended Dismax Parser) however, does.

Use the edismax parser instead if you want to provide queries as regular lucene query syntax. In general you'd however be better off having the query as london - i.e. `q=london` and then use `qf` to tell edismax which fields you want to search - `qf=NAME`.

Your query string does then become `q=london&qf=NAME&defType=edismax` - this query would however behave the same using the older dismax parser as well.

Comment: I am confused. Same query works with dismax and without q.alt. That's where my confusion started.

Comment: How can I query in dismax parser if "The dismax parser does not support the Lucene syntax (field:value)"?  Is it the same way you specified for `edismax`? Why is it so confusing with same fields like `q` has different meaning on different parsers?

Comment: The `q` is the query. The query parser parses the query according to its rules - that's what the query _parser_ does - it parses the query. Different query parses allows different kinds of syntax to achieve different goals - the (e)dismax query parses are great for handling more natural user queries, instead of users having to use the Lucene syntax directly (and know field names, etc.). They serve different purposes - but they still parse _the query_ (`q`).